# (kdb+/q) Pivot table: date in rows, symbols in columns, last price as values

Tags: pivot-table, kdb, q-lang

General pivot function provided at http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/pivoting-tables/ goes:

```
piv:{[t;k;p;v;f;g]
 v:(),v;
 G:group flip k!(t:.Q.v t)k;
 F:group flip p!t p;
 count[k]!g[k;P;C]xcols 0!key[G]!flip(C:f[v]P:flip value flip key F)!raze
  {[i;j;k;x;y]
   a:count[x]#x 0N;
   a[y]:x y;
   b:count[x]#0b;
   b[y]:1b;
   c:a i;
   c[k]:first'[a[j]@'where'[b j]];
   c}[I[;0];I J;J:where 1<>count'[I:value G]]/:\:[t v;value F]}
```

given that `f` and `g` are defined as

```
 f:{[v;P]`$raze each string raze P[;0],'/:v,/:\:P[;1]}
 g:{[k;P;c]k,(raze/)flip flip each 5 cut'10 cut raze reverse 10 cut asc c}
```

Now this example works (see the above link how table `q` is defined):

```
piv[`q;`date`sym`time;`side`level;`price`size;f;g]

date       sym  time        | Bprice0 Bsize0 Aprice0  Asize0 Bprice1  Bsize1 ..
----------------------------| -----------------------------------------------..
2009.01.05 milg 09:30:00.187|                                93.56285 29     ..
2009.01.05 milg 09:30:15.798|                                                ..
2009.01.05 milg 09:30:30.627|                                                ..
```

---

In my case, I would like to pivot by `sym` (each column different symbol) and key by `date` (each row different date), values being last `price` (each cell last price for a given date and symbol).

This naive call doesn't work:

```
piv[`q;`date;`sym;`price;f;g]
```

How to redefine `f` and `g` functions to be able to get a table of last price for each distinct date and each symbol, yielding something like this?

```
date       |  syma    symb     symc 
-----------| ----------------------
2009.01.05 | 93.56     8.5    566.1
2009.01.06 | 93.6      8.0    564.2
2009.01.07 |           9.0         
2009.01.08 | 94.05            560.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function `piv` requires the `key` and `pivot` arguments to be a list. So modifying your naive call as follows gives us a result:

```
q) piv[`q;(),`date;(),`sym;`price;f;g]
    date      | obhmprice oijbprice mkjkprice nihdprice ldegprice mbgnprice jmmip..
    ----------| -----------------------------------------------------------------..
    2009.01.08| 72.35531  28.9323   23.88535  12.21371  2.417089  49.45298  98.14..
    2009.01.07| 83.59946  6.036849  21.47751  78.8127   10.8295   98.52086  92.95..
    2009.01.09| 46.80912  46.26248  81.22377  93.51525  22.72674  95.42947  0.780..
    2009.01.05| 15.15728  26.88241  52.27362  90.73569  46.13635  50.67675  36.28..
    2009.01.06| 87.55843  38.49544  44.47115  59.41535  28.59271  94.38644  72.12..
```

> ...values being last price...

You will need to pre-process the quote data as follows to get the last price:

```
q) piv[0!select last price by date,sym from `date`time xasc q;(),`date;(),`sym;`price;f;g]
    date      | obhmprice oijbprice mkjkprice nihdprice ldegprice mbgnprice jmmip..
    ----------| -----------------------------------------------------------------..
    2009.01.05| 68.45829  95.92887  55.64212  82.06286  86.33655  6.020653  49.99..
    2009.01.06| 80.80825  39.97803  44.47115  20.84011  95.24609  26.23889  21.87..
    2009.01.07| 30.9605   15.85936  2.112642  74.48924  63.82276  49.55288  9.791..
    2009.01.08| 40.17655  34.08045  49.43202  59.99883  68.43116  74.76724  96.43..
    2009.01.09| 5.628707  96.54884  93.37123  65.68942  12.78308  91.10505  59.37..
```

Finally, to get the column name to be the symbol name, you need to modify the `f` and `g` functions - can review the documentation [here](http://code.kx.com/q/cookbook/pivoting-tables/#a-very-general-pivot-function-and-an-example) or simply add some debug prints to see what is passed to these functions to understand what they should be.

In your case, they can simply be set to the following:

```
q) piv[0!select last price by date,sym from `date`time xasc q;(),`date;(),`sym;`price;{y[;0]};{x,z}]
    date      | abaa     aeec     agom     ahnj     amlj     aogk     bbfc     be..
    ----------| -----------------------------------------------------------------..
    2009.01.05| 1.382202 16.05533 33.8328  31.08264 82.60021 87.60909 37.37758 82..
    2009.01.06| 14.96261 35.70751 11.48701 5.394078 47.38052 79.5398  31.46943 64..
    2009.01.07| 12.95503 17.96305 92.59666 89.16665 83.80779 15.04835 34.70387 9...
    2009.01.08| 39.33969 15.18487 2.20252  8.859751 43.23156 22.88771 15.73866 76..
    2009.01.09| 48.32295 18.01393 91.38    46.87793 45.88258 67.70167 57.27067 63..
```

Comment: Thank you for insights, it worked for my case, except that I had to define ``f:{[v;P] `$raze each string raze P[;0]}`` instead of your proposal `f:{y[;0]}` (or `f:{P[;0]}`)

Comment: Auxiliary question: The http://code.kx.com/wiki/Pivot says that `f` and `g` can be defaulted with (::) - how would the syntax look like in that case?